# Calculate derivative and use the result as a function

Tags: r

I need to calculate a derivative, say f = x^2. I am using the code

```
D(expression(x^2), 'x')
```

How do I use the output of D(x^2) = 2x as a function that will take values?

Answer (score 2):

```
k<-deriv(~ x^2, "x")
x <- -1:10
eval(k)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to convert the results to a function:

```
> myfun <- function(x) {}
> body(myfun) <- D( expression(x^2), 'x' )
> 
> myfun( 1:10 )
 [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```